# Which files are compiled?

Tags: go

How to know which files are going to be compiled and linked when you have several files which are specific to a system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least a couple of options:

1. Use `go build -n` to list the commands that would be executed by a build, and then parse the output.
2. Use the [`go/build`](http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/) package. Specifically, look at the [Import](http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#Import) function.

I suggest the second method; if I understand your question correctly it does what you need. You specify a package to "import", and it returns a `Package` structure which contains, among other things, the set of Go, C, ASM files that will be compiled.